# Drools - Finding a single matching condition for a table of products ranked by consumers

Tags: drools, rule-engine

I have a table displaying information for the top four ratings of produce in a store. I want to be able to find specific products in this rating table. Here is a structure of the table

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
sectId  |    product_code     |   product_category   | consumer_raniking       
10444   |     11222           |   PRODUCE            | RATING_1                     
10444   |     45555           |   PRODUCE            | RATING_1
10444   |     10005           |   PR0DUCE            | RATING_1
20555   |     11344           |   PRODUCE            | RATING_2
20555   |     94003           |   PRODUCE            | RATING_2
```

... and so on.

I wrote a rule to find inserted products which ins not working the way I want, i.e. to find the targetted fact that was inserted into the table.  Here is the rule I put together:

```
rule "find by product codes rating_1"

   when 
     $product_table: ProductRanking( $rank1:  this.getProductCodesRankFirst())
     $product1 : Product(  this.product_code memberOf $rank1, $product_code: product_code )
     $product2 : Product( this.product_code == 10444,this.product_code != $product_code ,$product_code2: product_code)
   then
    System.out.println("Found Products for product_codes "+$product_code+ " "+$product_code2 ) ;
 end
```

Unfortunately, this returns 3 rows. I inserted into the session the product in row 2 i.e. product with ocde 45555 and it does find row 2. However, ir also brings in row 1 and row3.
I can see why it's doing that. It's because the skus are in the sectId with sectId 10444.  However, I want to only bring in the row
that I inserted, which is sectionId(10444), product_code(45555). How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using a global to filter out the extra products. In the first line that brings the rankings, I eliminate the extra-matching products this way:

```
 global ProductHelper productHelper



$product_table: ProductRanking( $rank1:  productHelper.getProductCodesRankFirst(), 

 productCode != productHelper.getProductCodeFruitCategory() && productCode!= 

         productHelper.productCodeVegetableCategory())
```

The ProductHelper identifies the product codes I want to eliminate and hence the extra 2 products brought in are ignored, creating a single match. I'm sure there is a better way, but since I'm no expert, this is what I was able to come up with.